# URL keeps changing when running a docker container on localhost in a --network

Tags: docker

I am using this guide:
https://github.com/osixia/docker-phpLDAPadmin

to start two containers: OpenLDAP and phpldapadmin. I start them with:

```
docker run --network=$NETWORK_NAME --name $LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME --detach --hostname $LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME -p 389:389 -p 689:689 $LDAP_IMAGE_NAME

docker run --network=$NETWORK_NAME --name $PHP_LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME --detach --hostname $PHP_LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=$LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME $PHP_LDAP_IMAGE_NAME
```

Now the `$PHP_LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME` I access from my browser on https://172.18.0.4/ but yesterday when I ran it was on https://172.18.0.3/. Is there anyway to keep it on the same location and use something like: http://localhost:xxxx where `xxxx` is a static port?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Publish the 443 port like this:

```
docker run --network=$NETWORK_NAME --name $PHP_LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME --detach --hostname $PHP_LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME --env PHPLDAPADMIN_LDAP_HOSTS=$LDAP_CONTAINER_NAME -p 443:443 $PHP_LDAP_IMAGE_NAME
```

Just add the `-p 443:443` to your last command.

Comment: That works! I can now access it on https://localhost:443. I then need to add a security exception and then it "falls back" to localhost without port. Is 443 some magic "port" ? I only found something mentioned about 389 here: http://phpldapadmin.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Server:server:tls

Comment: The 443 port is the port used for HTTPS (HTTP + TLS).  You don't need to specify add the 443 port to the URL if you use `https://localhost`.